# How to add an object to an empty array using typescript in useMemo react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to push an object into an empty array in useMemo method using typescript. i have code like below,

```
const commonDetails = data?.CommonDetails;

const details: Details[] = [];

const selectedItems = React.useMemo(() => { // here selectedItems type is set to 
// number or undefined. instead i expect it to be of type Details[] too as i push 
// commonDetails which is an object into details which is array.
    return commonDetails && details.push(commonDetails);
}, [commonDetails]);


console.log('selectedItems', selectedItems); //this outputs 1. but i expect an array 
// of object
```

could someone help me with this. i am not sure why the selectedItems is number instead of array of object. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Array.push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.

```
const selectedItems = React.useMemo(() => { 
    return commonDetails? [...details, commonDetails] : [];
}, [commonDetails]);
```

If `commonDetails` is an `array`, `[...details, ...commonDetails]`

Hope this would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note here:

1. [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array after pushing.
2. The [AND(`&&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) operator preserves non-Boolean values and returns them as they are. && evaluates operands from left to right, returning immediately with the value of the first `falsy` operand it encounters; if all values are `truthy`, the value of the last operand is returned.

With the above in mind, one can understand why the below statements log what they do:

```js
console.log({} && [2].push(5)); //2
console.log(true && [].push(5)); //1
```

Similarly,

```
return commonDetails && details.push(commonDetails);
```

will return 1 (if details is empty initially and commonDetails is `truthy`).

You can change your code like:

```
const selectedItems = React.useMemo(() => { 
  if(commonDetails) return [...details,commonDetails];
  return details;
}, [commonDetails]);
```

Also, try to not mutate and create new references.

Answer (score 0):

[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) return count
const commonDetails = data?.CommonDetails;

```
const details: Details[] = [];

const selectedItems = React.useMemo(() => { 
    return commonDetails ? [ ...details, commonDetails] : [];
}, [commonDetails, details]); // this will most likey need the dependencies
```

details array might need to be included if it is  a prop